# print function variables if get exception - KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

In the following simple example, I have a function `foo()` do something. There is a variable `a` inside the function. What I would like to do is that when the program catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`, the local functional variable `a` can be printed.

Clearly, the following way is not working. Is there anyway can do this?

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    for _ in xrange(10000):
        a += 1
    return a

try:
    a = foo()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print a
```

**Updates (answer some comments below regarding why I want to Control-C)**:

Actually, my intention is to stop my Keras RNN training process earlier.  Like the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

def train():
    model = Sequential()
    ....
    model.build()
    ....
    for iteration in range(1, 200):
        ....
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, ...)
        ....
    ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        model = train()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        model.save_weights("weights.hdf5")
```

If I stop the training process early, I would like to save the current model weights.

Comment: Can you use a debugger?

Comment: @Francesco what do you mean by debugger?

Comment: Well, from the docs: "Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally `Control-C` or `Delete`)". so do do you really want this or when the user press any key instead?

Comment: regarding why I want to `Control-C`, please see my question updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create your `model` *outside* the `train` function, and then pass `model` as an argument to `train`. That way you have a valid reference to `model` in case you interrupt `train` with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> before it returns.

Eg,

```
from keras.models import Sequential

def train(model):
    model.build()
    ....
    for iteration in range(1, 200):
        ....
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, ...)
        ....
    ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        model = Sequential()
        train(model)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        model.save_weights("weights.hdf5")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `a` is local to `foo()`. Either you need to make it global OR you want to add your exception catch inside `foo()`. Here's an example of the latter

```
def foo():
    try:
        a = 1
        for _ in xrange(10000):
            a += 1
        return a
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `foo()` never completes a is never assigned.  You'll need to break up your function so the caller knows it's last value at any given time.

```
def foo(a):
   return a + 1

try:
    for _ in xrange(10000):
        a = foo(a)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print a
```

Not sure there's much of a point of doing it that way, but for illustration.  You could also use a global variable but I don't like recommending that for most situations.